# Training procedure

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, theano

I noticed that the `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier` implements gradient descent for a *linear model*, therefore one could state that the class combines the fitting procedure (SGD) and the model (linear model) in one class.

SGD is, however, not inherent to linear models, and linear_models can be trained using many other optimizations with particular pro's (memory usage, convergence speed, local optima avoidance*, ...). One could state that such optimization techniques implement how to iterate over the training data, whether to do it online or offline, in what feature-dimension to apply an update and when to stop (possibly based on an error function of a validation set).

In particular, I implemented a model using theano and wrapped it in a fit/predict interface. Theano is cool because it allows one to define a callable which applies gradient descent on one sample, or on a set of samples, as well as a callable which returns the error on a validation set. But this coolness is not inherent to theano, a lot more models can simply define an update and error-evaluation function, which can then be used by different iteration- and stopping policies for fitting.

The theano examples often use minibatch, and the minibatch code is copy-pasted or reimplemented a lot with just minor adjustments which can easily be factored out. So I was hoping that sklearn implements something that you initialize with some parameters and an update/error callable to fit 'any model'. Or possible there is some good practice on how to do this yourself (especially w.r.t. the interface of the fitter).

Is there anything like this (in sklearn), that is Fitters which do not define the model?

*In the particular case of linear models and a l2 cost function, local optima do not exist of course, but still.

**EDIT**

Fair enough, this calls for a suggestion. I coded these two classes, which are not 100% clean, but they given an idea of what I mean:

```py
import numpy

class StochasticUpdate():
    def __init__(self, model, update, n_epochs, n_data_points, error=None, test_fraction=None):
        self.update = update
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        self.n_data_points = n_data_points
        self.error = error
        self.model = model
        if self.error is None and test_fraction is not None:
            raise ValueError('error parameter must be specified if a test_faction (value: %s) should be used.' % test_fraction)
        self.do_test = test_fraction is not None
        self.n_train_samples = int(n_data_points - test_fraction) if self.do_test else n_data_points
        if self.do_test:
            self.test_range = numpy.arange(self.n_train_samples, n_data_points)
            self.n_test_samples  = int(n_data_points * test_fraction)
        self.train_range = numpy.arange(0, self.n_train_samples)

    def fit(self):
        if self.do_test: self.test_errors = []
        self.train_errors = []
        self.mean_cost_values = []
        for epoch in range(self.n_epochs):
            order = numpy.random.permutation(self.n_train_samples)
            mean_cost_value = 0
            for i in range(self.n_train_samples):
                mean_cost_value += self.update([order[i]])

            self.mean_cost_values.append(mean_cost_value/ self.n_data_points)
            if self.error is not None:
                self.train_errors.append(self.error(self.train_range))
                if self.do_test:
                    self.test_errors.append(self.error(self.test_range))
        return self.model

from math import ceil
class MinibatchStochasticUpdate(StochasticUpdate):
    def __init__(self, model, update, n_epochs, n_data_points, error, batch_size, patience=5000, patience_increase=2,
                 improvement_threshold = 0.995, validation_frequency=None, validate_faction=0.1, test_fraction=None):
        super().__init__(self, model, update, n_data_points, error, test_fraction)
        self.update = update
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        self.n_data_points = n_data_points
        self.model = model
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.patience = patience
        self.patience_increase = patience_increase
        self.improvement_threshold = improvement_threshold
        self.n_validation_samples = int(n_data_points * validate_faction)
        self.validation_range = numpy.arange(self.n_train_samples, self.n_train_samples + self.n_validation_samples)
        self.n_train_batches = int(ceil(n_data_points / batch_size))

        self.n_train_batches = int(ceil(self.n_train_samples / self.batch_size))
        self.train_batch_ranges = [
            numpy.arange(minibatch_index * self.batch_size, min((minibatch_index+1) * self.batch_size, self.n_train_samples))
            for minibatch_index in range(self.n_train_batches)
        ]

        self.validation_frequency = min(self.n_train_batches, patience/2) if validation_frequency is None else validation_frequency

    def fit(self):
        self.best_validation_error = numpy.inf
        best_params = None

        iteration = 0
        for epoch in range(self.n_epochs):
            for minibatch_index in range(self.n_train_batches):
                self.update(self.train_batch_ranges[minibatch_index])
                if (iter + 1) % self.validation_frequency == 0:
                    current_validation_error = self.error(self.validation_error)

                    if current_validation_error < self.best_validation_error:
                        if current_validation_error < self.best_validation_error * self.improvement_threshold:
                            patience = max(self.patience, iter * self.patience_increase)
                        best_params = self.model.copy_parameters()
                        self.best_validation_error = current_validation_error

                if iteration <= patience:
                    self.model.set_parameters(best_params)
                    return self.model
                iteration += 1
        self.model.set_parameters(best_params)
        return self.model
```

Then for in the fit of the model one could support different training approaches and stopping criteria like this:

```py
def fit(self, X, y):
    X_shared = theano.shared(X, borrow=True)
    y_shared = theano.shared(y, borrow=True)
    learning_rate = self.training_method_options['learning_rate']

    trainer = {
        'stochastic_gradient_descent': lambda: StochasticUpdate(
            self,
            update=self.update_stochastic_gradient_descent_function(X_shared, y_shared, learning_rate),
            n_epochs=self.training_method_options['n_epochs'],
            n_data_points=X.shape[0],
            error=self.evaluation_function(X_shared, y_shared),
        ),
        'minibatch_gradient_descent': lambda: MinibatchStochasticUpdate(
            self,
            update=self.update_stochastic_gradient_descent_function(X_shared, y_shared, learning_rate),
            n_epochs=self.training_method_options['n_epochs'],
            n_data_points=X.shape[0],
            error=self.evaluation_function(X_shared, y_shared),
            batch_size=self.training_method_options['batch_size']
        )
    }[self.training_method]()

    trainer.fit()

    return self
```

Obviosuly the hash-map part is hacky, and could be done more elegantly using a standardized interface for the two classes above (since the hashmaps are still O(N*M) in size for N fitters and M models).

Comment: If you want to choose best model - you can try to iterate over all possible estimators, or over Classifiers/Regressors/Clusterers only.

Comment: This is not about model selection / parameter election, this is about avoiding duplicate code for different fitting procedures on different models. Or to put it different, one would want to have O(N+M) amount of code for M models and N fitting strategies, not O(N*M). I will update my question with some example code soon.